# How to center Text and make as big as given size

Tags: flutter, dart, layout, flutter-layout

I have a view, where I have GestureDetector which has onHorizontalDragEnd function.
As a child I want to have centered Text and possibility to swipe horizontally starting from every place on screen.
My problem is that when I put Text in Center widget I can only swipe only when I start on Text.

I tried to wrap Text with Container. It fixes problem with swiping, but Text is not centered.

Here is how it looks now:

```
Center(
   child: Container(
   height: size.height * 0.6,
   child: Text(
       'example text',
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       ),
   ),
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `alignment: Alignment.center` in your container

```dart
Center(
   child: Container(
   height: size.height * 0.6,
   alignment: Alignment.center, //HERE
   child: Text(
       'example text',
       textAlign: TextAlign.center,
       ),
   ),
)
```

Comment: Text is centered, but I can swipe only when I touch directly on Text after adding alignment

Comment: add this  `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent` on your `GestureDetector`

Comment: Oh yes, it's finally working. Thank u so much!